# Issues with DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to make a simple Date and Time pickers for my app. These is the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnersShown="true"
             />
...Rest of the code
```

And this is how I see it:

[image]

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a possibility not to display the AM/PM button, just the 24h format clock?
2. Why do I see the calendar that way? How can I make it show day/month/year normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
tp.setIs24HourView(true);
dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
dp.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```